# Can't access User Claims for logging from HttpContext using Serilog

Tags: logging, httpcontext, serilog, claims, asp-net-core-spa-services

I'm using Serilog as my logger in an ASP Net Core API project and I'd like to log the contents (claims) of the received access token. The claims should be in the User property of HttpContext object.

The problem is when I try to log the claims they aren't available. However, when I access the claims at later points in the app I can see them. In another project I had a similar issue and noticed that when I turned the Microsoft logging events from Information to Warning I could see the claims but when I switched back to Information they disappeared.

How can I log the user claims? Should this part of the logging be done in the Startup.cs middleware instead of Program.cs? Is Microsoft perhaps trying to block logging of PII? I'm at a loss here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

From the Program.cs:

```
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), @".\logs\log-bsw-startup-.txt",
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                    retainedFileCountLimit: null,
                    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
                 .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Building and running web host.");

                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Information("Could not start web host. {@ex}", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.Information("Closing web host.");
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog((provider, context, config) =>
                {
                    SerilogConfiguration.Configure(provider, context, config);
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

From the SerilogConfiguration.cs file:

```
        public static void Configure(
            IServiceProvider provider, 
            WebHostBuilderContext context, 
            LoggerConfiguration config)
        {
            var name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName();

            var aspNetCoreEnvironment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            if (aspNetCoreEnvironment == null)
                throw new Exception($"No ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT found.");

            var connectionString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
            if (connectionString == null)
                throw new Exception($"No connection string in appsettings.json for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT '{aspNetCoreEnvironment}'.");

            var batchPostingLimit = context.Configuration
                .GetSection("Logging")
                .GetValue("BatchPostingLimit", 1);

            var sqlLogTable = context.Configuration
                .GetSection("Logging")
                .GetValue<string>("SqlLogTable", null);
            if (sqlLogTable == null)
                throw new Exception("No SQL log table in appsettings.json");

            var options = new ColumnOptions();
            options.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties); // Removes XML config
            options.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent); // Adds JSON config
            options.Id.ColumnName = "id";
            options.Message.ColumnName = "message";
            options.MessageTemplate.ColumnName = "message_template";
            options.TimeStamp.ColumnName = "timestamp";
            options.Exception.ColumnName = "exception";
            options.Level.ColumnName = "level";
            options.LogEvent.ColumnName = "log_event";
            options.LogEvent.ExcludeStandardColumns = true;

            config.MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("IdentityServer4", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                .Enrich.WithThreadName()
                .Enrich.WithProcessId()
                .Enrich.WithProcessName()
                .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("LogId", $"{Guid.NewGuid()}")
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Assembly", $"{name.Name}")
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", $"{name.Version}")
                .Enrich.WithProperty("AspNetCoreEnvironment", $"{aspNetCoreEnvironment}")
                .Enrich.WithAspnetcoreHttpcontext(provider, CustomHttpContextEnricher);

            config.WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, sqlLogTable, columnOptions: options,
                batchPostingLimit: batchPostingLimit,
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information);

            config.WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), @".\logs\log-.txt",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                retainedFileCountLimit: null,
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true);
        }

        private static HttpContextProperties CustomHttpContextEnricher(
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            var context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            if (context == null)
                return null;

            var contextIndex = "http-properties";

            // Short circuit if there's already a context properties object available
            var contextProperties = context.Items[contextIndex] as HttpContextProperties;
            if (contextProperties != null)
                return contextProperties;

            var user = context.User;
            var isAuthenticated = false;
            string internalUserId = null;
            string email = null;
            var userClaims = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var i = 1;

// Here's where I'm trying to grab the user claims. When I do logger.LogInformation I would think the user claims would be available but they aren't. 
            if (user != null)
            {
                isAuthenticated = user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

                var userId = "user_id";
                if (user.HasClaim(c => c.Type == userId))
                    internalUserId = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(
                        c => c.Type == userId).Value.ToString();

                if (user.HasClaim(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email))
                    email = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(
                        c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email).Value.ToString();

                userClaims = user.Claims.ToDictionary(x => $"{i++.ToString("D2")}-{x.Type}", y => y.Value.ToString());
            }

            var properties = new HttpContextProperties
            {
                IpAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                Host = context.Request.Host.ToString(),
                Path = context.Request.Path.ToString(),
                IsHttps = context.Request.IsHttps,
                Scheme = context.Request.Scheme,
                Method = context.Request.Method,
                ContentType = context.Request.ContentType,
                Protocol = context.Request.Protocol,
                QueryString = context.Request.QueryString.ToString(),
                Query = context.Request.Query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.ToString()),
                Headers = context.Request.Headers
                    .Where(x => !(x.Key.ToString() == "Authorization")) // Remove from logs for security purposes
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.ToString()),
                UserClaims = userClaims,
                InternalUserId = internalUserId,
                Email = email,
                IsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
            };

            context.Items[contextIndex] = properties;

            return properties;
        }

        public class HttpContextProperties
        {
            public string Path { get; set; }
            public string Host { get; set; }
            public string Method { get; set; }
            public string IpAddress { get; set; }
            public bool IsHttps { get; set; }
            public string Scheme { get; set; }
            public string ContentType { get; set; }
            public string Protocol { get; set; }
            public string QueryString { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> Query { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> Headers { get; set; }
            public string InternalUserId { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> UserClaims { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer or not but it might help - the .Net Core stuff is all a bit of a mystery at the moment so this might help you a little bit (you may also have this in your startup.cs anyway):

I was trying to tap into the pipeline in my startup.cs to trigger a redirect to the identity server login prior to loading the SPA service (I don't want users to even attempt loading the SPA unless they're authenticated.

I found that IsAuthenticate in the following code (in configure method) in my Startup.cs was always false:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync("Identity.Application");
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

Until I added this code (in ConfigureService method) to my startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    //The following two may not be as relevant as the first two.
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```